# What can cause a cursor to fail?

Tags: android, android-cursor

I am creating an Android app with Eclipse and trying to use a `Cursor` to query a SQLite database. I can't figure out what is causing this cursor to fail:

```
public List<Word> getAllWords() {
    List<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>(); 

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {FIELD_PRIMARY_DEFINITION}, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.close();

    return words;
}
```

When I run this code, my Android emulator says the program has stopped. When I comment out the cursor line, it runs fine. The database exists, the table exists, `TABLE_NAME` contains the correct name of the table and `FIELD_PRIMARY_DEFINITION` contains the name of a column. Is there anything I'm missing that can cause this to fail?

Thank you.

I'm not familiar with Logcat, I'm new to Android development. But I did a filter on my app name and here's what it shows:

```
02-18 22:26:08.447: I/jdwp(20692): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
02-18 22:26:15.107: W/Trace(20989): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-18 22:26:15.148: W/Trace(20989): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-18 22:26:15.187: D/AndroidRuntime(20989): Shutting down VM
02-18 22:26:15.187: W/dalvikvm(20989): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.source.wordCollector/com.source.wordCollector.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.source.dal.WordDAO.getAllWords(WordDAO.java:75)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.source.wordCollector.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-18 22:26:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: add here logcat please.

Comment: did you initialize `db` ?

Comment: I'm quite sure he's missing a space in his CREATE TABLE statement and getting the column name messed up.

Comment: Try just hitting run instead of debug. It seems your exception isn't logged because your app is waiting for the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to log and check the dynamic query your are writing and make sure there is no syntax error. Most of the cases, this would probably lead an android cursor to fail.

Also make sure that the connection to the database is open. I suggest you take a look at this article:

[www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: Ah drat, my database wasn't open. You nailed it, thank you. I was looking too closely at that bit of code and not at the problem with the bigger picture.

Comment: no problem my friend. Also don't forget to close the connection once you finished using it, yet after you make the necessary queries!